# Format Python numpy array output

Tags: python, numpy, formatting

How do I get this code to always return 1 decimal for every element in the array?

```
import numpy as np

def mult_list_with_x(liste, skalar):
    print(np.array(liste) * skalar)

liste = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3]
skalar = 2

mult_list_with_x(liste, skalar)
```

I.e.:
[2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0]

not
[2. 3. 4. 5. 6.]

Comment: I understand. But that is sort of the question :) How is each array element converted to strings with the correct format?

Can it be done in the print command - or do they have to be converted first and then printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.set_printoptions`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) to set the format:

```
import numpy as np

def mult_list_with_x(liste, skalar):
    print(np.array(liste) * skalar)

liste = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3]
skalar = 2

np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': '{: 0.1f}'.format})

mult_list_with_x(liste, skalar)
```

Output:

```
[ 2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0]
```

Note that this np printoptions setting is permanent - see below for a temporary option.
Or to reset the defaults afterwards use:

```
np.set_printoptions(formatter=None)
np.get_printoptions()  # to check the settings
```

---

An option to **temporarily set the print options** - kudos to [mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway) for the hint in the comments!:

```
with np.printoptions(formatter={'float': '{: 0.1f}'.format}):
    print(np.array(liste) * skalar)
```

---

An option to **just format the print output** as string:

```
print(["%.1f" % x for x in ( np.array(liste) * skalar)])
```

Output:

```
['2.0', '3.0', '4.0', '5.0', '6.0']
```

Choose an option fitting how the output should further be used.

Comment: Thank you :) 

Assuming then, that you can't do it directly in the print command? (Just for curiosity)

Comment: Note that you can use [`numpy.printoptions`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.printoptions.html#numpy.printoptions) as context manager for a temporary change.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this setup first:

```
float_formatter = "{:.1f}".format
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float_kind':float_formatter})
```

Output

```
[2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0]
```